# Insert and Update in log(n) time with better performance

Tags: java, algorithm, dictionary, binary-search-tree

I am developing some financial algorithms using Java. I have a complex data structure with many properties that need to be updated during the life time of the algorithm. Sometimes this data structure is updated more than 1000 times ...

To improve the performance especially for `get(search)/update/insert` I decided to use `TreeMap` as a container which is quite efficient in that regard.

Now comes the challenging part. I need to update the data-structure properties for which I need to retrieve it from the container which requires:

1. check if container has the object
2. if yes, then get the object, else create new object and add to map
3. update the object if it is present in the container

This process takes THREE x log(n) i.e check, get and put. I want to do this in SINGLE log(n) time.

For that, my solution is:

I always add the object in the map (`insert/update/get`) using `put`. `put` returns the old object, I update the current object with the old values, which solves log(n) but different object lost reference to previous object because the new value is replaced in the map.

Is there any better solution or better container for updating the datastructure. I can use a `List` and use Binary Search of collections but for that I need to sort the datastructure again as list is not sorted.

Kindly Guide

Comment: Is there a reason you're not using a `HashMap`?

Comment: HashMap converts into LinkedList when we have many objects map to single hash/key which is bad

Comment: your hash function should be written so as to reduce collisions.

Comment: Good in terms of thinking  , but still hash function will not solve in the long run

Comment: Not sure why you are not trusting hashmaps, but they ARE better solution, unless you depend on ordering. I would suggest doing few tests for your particular case using non-trivial size of map to see the difference.

Comment: @DigitalAlchemist Although there could some collisions, but you will still get near O(n) with HashMap compared to always O(log n) with TreeMap. HashMap looks like a better choice. By the way, any rough idea, how many entries would be there in your TreeMap?

Comment: @MadhusudanaReddySunnapu 200 to 300 Maximum but in worst case it can go to 1000 to 3000 as well

Comment: @DigitalAlchemist With worst case of 3000 entries the complexity with TreeMap would be log3000 to base 2 which is around 12. With Hashmap it would still be O(1) = 1. Since hashcode() function returns an int field it can return 2^31 (2,147,483,647) unique hashcodes (not necessarily those many buckets in hashmap). **Correction** In my above comment I have specified Hashmap complexity as O(n) by, mistake, instead of O(1). Unless you want to support range queries. On a side note, as one of the members has suggested, you want to consider leveraging ConcurrentHashMap and putIfAbsent(...) semantics.

Comment: I mean, unless you want to support range queries, for which TreeMap is best candidate, IMO, sacrificing O(1) complexity provided by Hashmap and incurring O(log n) complexity may not justify.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are doing pretty good.

> O(k.log(n)) = O(log(n))

where k is a constant. So your time complexity is actually `O(log(n))`

Comment: Thanks, but wat about object reference missing when new value is added

Comment: I meant I don't see any disadvantage in using TreeMap. 3 times Log(n) won't affect the performance as I said, it is a constant. You will have to compromise on space complexity if you still want to make it just Log(n)

Comment: No, you don't need to compromise on space complexity. Methods like computeIfAbsent/merge will be pure log(n) with no extra storage requirement.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve `1` and `2` in one hit if you switch to [ConcurrentMap.computeIfAbsent(...)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentMap.html#computeIfAbsent-K-java.util.function.Function-). It returns the new/old object so you can update it.

If Java-7 then [putIfAbsent](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentMap.html#putIfAbsent%28K,%20V%29) but that requires an extra `new` - perhaps a bad thing if construction is expensive.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I have not been aware of computeIfAbsent (compute,merge etc) addition in ConcurrentMap.

Answer (score 1):

If you are not scared of having mutable objects around (which you seem to have given your proposed solution), you can do it with 1-2 operations. Instead of

```
1. contains()
2a. exists? get(), modify, put()
2b. doesn't exist? create, put()
```

you can just do

```
1. get()
2a. null? create put()
2b. not-null? modify object contents, as you already have reference
```

this way you have 1 search op for existing objects and 2 search ops for non-existing objects.

If you want to improve it further, you may want to use ConcurrentHashMap (after you get over your distrust of hashcodes ;) and putIfAbsent

```
1. old = putIfAbsent(createFresh())
2. old not null? update old
```

Said all that, I'm generally trying to avoid mutable objects for things longer than lifetime of single method. At some point you might want to multithread your processing and having mutable things is going to make it a lot more complicated. But there are various tradeoffs (like memory pressure), so it is up to you. But please look into hashmaps seriously, they are probably biggest optimalization you can do here, regardless of object (im)mutability.